# Where do I go after the E.M.M.I. are deactivated?

Tags: metroid-dread

I met a scientist named Quiet Robe in Ferenia who revealed that the Chozo attacking me is named Raven Beak and explained why the E.M.M.I were chasing Samus. Quiet Robe then proceeded to deactivate the remaining E.M.M.I. Now I'm lost and can't figure out where to go next.

Where do I go after Quiet Robe deactivates the remaining E.M.M.I.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Quiet Robe deactivated the E.M.M.I., he should've also opened up a new way in Burenia (the area where half the level is underwater).

Just in case you still want to figure it out for yourself, the rest of the answer will be hidden behind spoilers.

> When you first entered Burenia, you might remember a room with a visible area above its ceiling, which appears to be inaccessible. Silent Robe raised that ceiling to make the area accessible.

If you can't remember that room, here's a map of Burenia with the room marked in a red rectangle (ignore the red cursors):

> [image: Map of Burenia]

And this is what the room looks like in game (the path forward has already been opened; the minimap shows you where you haven't yet been):

> [image: Room in Burenia with the ceiling lifted]